# No launcher or menu bar in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity

My system has a Windows 8 dual boot with Ubuntu,but now when I boot in to Ubuntu only  desktop loads and nothing else. I can only open the terminal `tty`and there's no launcher menu bar. The super key isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to boot from a live USB (with 14.04) on a new machine that has Win8 installed. I changed the boot settings to legacy mode (non-uefi, non-secure), which solved the problem.